# Mocha mysql knex before each fails: Can't take lock to run migrations

Tags: javascript, mysql, mocha.js, knex.js

Here is my test setup code

```js
const knex = require('../db').knex

beforeEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback()
  .then(() => knex.migrate.latest())
  .then(() => knex.seed.run())
)

afterEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback()
  .then(() => {})
)
```

get the following error

```
Knex:warning - Can't take lock to run migrations: Migration table is already locked
Knex:warning - If you are sure migrations are not running you can release the lock manually by deleting all the rows from migrations lock table: knex_migrations_lock
Unhandled rejection MigrationLocked: Migration table is already locked

      1) "before each" hook for "is not allowed"
Knex:warning - Can't take lock to run migrations: Migration table is already locked
Knex:warning - If you are sure migrations are not running you can release the lock manually by deleting all the rows from migrations lock table: knex_migrations_lock
      2) "after each" hook for "is not allowed"
```

here is `db.js`

```js
const Knex = require('knex')
const Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')
const config = require('config')

var bookshelf = null
var knex = null

exports.init = () => {
  knex = Knex(config.get('database'))
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    knex.migrate.latest()
  }

  bookshelf = Bookshelf(knex)
  bookshelf.plugin('registry')
  bookshelf.plugin('pagination')
  bookshelf.plugin('bookshelf-camelcase')
  bookshelf.plugin('visibility')

  exports.bookshelf = bookshelf
  exports.knex = knex

}
```

`mocha.opts`

```
--ui bdd
--slow 70
--growl
--recursive
--reporter spec
```

Comment: If you run only one test, does it still happen? Are you running multiple tests parallel? Does error happen if you are not running seed?

Comment: Not sure how I could be running tests in parallel I am simply running `nyc _mocha`. Yes the error still happens if I comment out seed. Sometimes I can run several tests before one of the `afterEach`/`beforeEach` hook fails

Comment: I edited my answer, now that db init code is also added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `beforeEach` hook was taking a long time because of mysql.

Using `this.timeout` solved it for me!

```
beforeEach(async function () {
  this.timeout(60 * 1000)
  await knex.migrate.rollback()
  await knex.migrate.latest()
  return knex.seed.run()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all rows in migrations_lock table and try again. Probably some migration has crashed and left lock in place.

Also you shouldn't need done callbacks. Just returning promise from before/after should be enough:

```
const knex = require('../db').knex

beforeEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback()
  .then(() => knex.migrate.latest())
  .then(() => knex.seed.run())
)

afterEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback())
```

EDIT:

Your db init is running `knex.migrate.latest()`and not waiting that it completes before returning the function.

```
exports.init = () => {
  knex = Knex(config.get('database'))
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    // this starts running migrations and execution continues without waiting that this is ready 
    knex.migrate.latest() 
  }

  bookshelf = Bookshelf(knex)
  bookshelf.plugin('registry')
  bookshelf.plugin('pagination')
  bookshelf.plugin('bookshelf-camelcase')
  bookshelf.plugin('visibility')

  exports.bookshelf = bookshelf
  exports.knex = knex
}
```

Comment: I already tried doing `DELETE from knex_migrations_lock` but no luck. Issue reappears

Comment: That `knex.migrate.latest()` is never run because I am running tests in test env. However, I did add an `await`, thanks, good catch.

Comment: Looks like you just need ti reduce your test code to smaller and smaller until you get the exact row when the error happens and full log from `DEBUG=knex:*`  environment variable which should show which migrations are running at the same time.